# Linking valueBox title to different tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Suppose you have a basic `shinydashboard` app with two tabPanels within a `tabBox`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(width = 12, 
             tabBox(width = 12,
                    tabPanel("Info 1",
                             fluidRow(
                               valueBoxOutput("box")
                             )
                    ) ,

                    tabPanel("Info 2",
                             "Some Info about Tab 2."  
                    )
             )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$box<-renderValueBox(     

    valueBox(
      value = "ValueBox Title",
      subtitle = tagList("Some information about the box.",
                         p(""),
                         "Some more information about the box."
      ),
      icon = icon("user-check"),
      color = "green"
    ))

}

app<-shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, host="0.0.0.0",port=5060, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

In one `tabPanel` (called "Info 1" here) you have a `valueBox` with a title (in this case "ValueBox Title"). Is it possible to make the title of the `valueBox` a hyperlink such that it opens up the `tabPanel` called "Info 2"?

Within my app I wish to have a `tabPanel` which shows summary information for the entire analysis. If a user wishes to drill down and get more information about the summary data presented in the `valueBox` I want to take them to a different tab which contains more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour you'll need to give an `id` to your `tabBox`, so you can update it via `updateTabsetPanel`.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    width = 12,
    tabBox(
      width = 12,
      id = "tabBoxId",
      tabPanel("Info 1",
               fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("box"))) ,
      tabPanel("Info 2",
               "Some Info about Tab 2.")
    )
  ))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$box <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = actionLink(
        inputId = "valueBoxLink",
        label = div("ValueBox Title", style = "color: white")
      ),
      subtitle = tagList(
        "Some information about the box.",
        p(""),
        "Some more information about the box."
      ),
      icon = icon("user-check"),
      color = "green"
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$valueBoxLink, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "tabBoxId", selected = "Info 2")
  })
}

app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5060, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

[image: Result]